# Add counting numbers to words in a list

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list like:

```
<w>Asf</w>
<k>BOO</k>
<l>leg</l>
<w>kum</w>
...
```

Now i want something like:

```
<w id='1'>Asf</w>
<k>BOO</k>
<l>leg</l>
<w id='2'>kum</w>
...
<w id='250'>mau</w>
...
```

So i want to add this `id='n'`, but only for that `<a>`. I can add stuff to that list, but i dont know how to do that with a counting number. I do not even know what to try. I can adress the `<w>` with regex and put something in it, but how can i put the counting id in?

What i tried:

```
chars = ('w', 'k','l')
tags = itertools.cycle(chars)
for word, tag in zip(my_list, tags):
    names1.append("<{0} id='1'>{1}</{0}>".format(tag, word))
    print("<{0} id='1'>{1}</{0}>".format(tag, word))
```

But thats totally wrong. I get that id for the start and ending tag, and its obviously not counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are asking. As I understand your question, you want to add an increasing `id` attribute to each of those `<w>` tags. You could try something like this:

```
data = ['<w>Asf</w>', '<k>BOO</k>', '<l>leg</l>', '<w>kum</w>']
counter = 0
for i, line in enumerate(data):
    if "<w>" in line:
        data[i] = line.replace("<w>", "<w id='{}'>".format(counter))
        counter += 1
print data
```

This uses a `counter` variable that is increased each time the lines contains a `<w>` tag. If you want to add ids to other tags, you can easily extend this to a function, taking `w` or any other tag name as a parameter.

Output:

```
["<w id='0'>Asf</w>", '<k>BOO</k>', '<l>leg</l>', "<w id='1'>kum</w>"]
```

Comment: Thats it. Thanks! I tried some wired stuff... But that worked totally fine!